# Wildfly error start

Tags: wildfly

I got some issues with Wildfly. 
I got this Exception but I don't know how to fix it...
I don't know what I could do know to fix this Problem...
.......................

```
21:58:09,529 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final
21:58:11,357 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.2.1.Final
21:58:12,201 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: WildFly 8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT "WildFly" starting
21:58:21,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] JBAS015014: Re-attempting 
failed deployment filesDB.war
21:58:21,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] JBAS015003: Found fi
lesDb.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called fi
lesDb.war.dodeploy
21:58:23,733 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] JBAS014612: Op
eration ("add") failed - address: ([("core-service" => "vault")]): java.lang.Run
timeException: JBAS015804: Error initializing vault --  org.jboss.as.server.serv
ices.security.VaultReaderException: JBAS013313: Vault Reader Exception:
        at org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultAddHandler.performRuntime(
VaultAddHandler.java:82) [wildfly-server-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.1.Final-SN
APSHOT]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddS
tepHandler.java:75) [wildfly-controller-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.1.Final-SNA
PSHOT]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(Abstract
OperationContext.java:591) [wildfly-controller-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.1.Fi
nal-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(Abstr
actOperationContext.java:469) [wildfly-controller-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.1
.Final-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal
(AbstractOperationContext.java:273) [wildfly-controller-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar
:8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(Abs
tractOperationContext.java:268) [wildfly-controller-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0
.1.Final-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.
java:333) [wildfly-controller-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractContro
llerService.java:294) [wildfly-controller-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.1.Final-S
NAPSHOT]
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:356) [wildf
ly-server-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:331) [wildf
ly-server-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractContr
ollerService.java:256) [wildfly-controller-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.1.Final-
SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.8.0]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultReaderException: JBAS01331
3: Vault Reader Exception:
        at org.jboss.as.security.vault.RuntimeVaultReader.createVault(RuntimeVau
ltReader.java:84) [wildfly-security-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHO
T]
        at org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultAddHandler.performRuntime(
VaultAddHandler.java:80) [wildfly-server-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.1.Final-SN
APSHOT]
        ... 11 more
Caused by: org.jboss.security.vault.SecurityVaultException: java.lang.NullPointe
rException
        at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.init(PicketBoxSecu
rityVault.java:210) [picketbox-4.0.21.Beta1.jar:4.0.21.Beta1]
        at org.jboss.as.security.vault.RuntimeVaultReader.createVault(RuntimeVau
ltReader.java:82) [wildfly-security-8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHO
T]
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.checkAndConvertKey
StoreToJCEKS(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:570) [picketbox-4.0.21.Beta1.jar:4.0.21
.Beta1]
        at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.init(PicketBoxSecu
rityVault.java:207) [picketbox-4.0.21.Beta1.jar:4.0.21.Beta1]
        ... 13 more

21:58:23,780 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in a
n unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
21:58:23,795 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: WildFly 8.0.1.Final-SNAPSHOT "Wild
Fly" stopped in 11ms
```

Can anyone please help me? Thank You!

Comment: Can you please share your vault configuration from standalone xml (or whichever you are using) file ?? I doubt this could occur because of path issue of vault. So just want to have a look at configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a NullPointerException, so unfortunately, it is a bug.  Please open an issue at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SECURITY with this same description.

Comment: I am getting the same exception. I am using WildFly 8.1.0.Final. I created the dodeploy file but still it complains that there is no dodeploy file. 09:37:53,725 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
09:37:53,977 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
09:37:54,046 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny" starting

Comment: 09:37:55,025 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found hello.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called hello.war.dodeploy
09:37:55,057 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found hello.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called hello.war.dodeploy
09:37:55,065 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "hello.war")])

Answer (score 0):

clean the server , or show in folder and delete all the folder exist in the deployment , and restart the server .